# Struggling with Responsive CSS and Google PageSpeed Insight

Tags: css, responsive-design, pagespeed

I'm struggling to get a site working with responsive CSS. I can get it to just about look OK on my iPhone, but then Google PageSpeed Insight shows lots of 'Size content to viewport' errors.

I can fix these errors by putting in extra statements with some absolute widths into my CSS but then everything is cramped into just a small portion of the left-hand side of the screen when viewing the site on and iPhone.

I've tried everything I can think of a but can't get the site to fill the full width of the screen on my phone and pass the test at Google PageSpeed Insight. Where am I going wrong?

You can see the site here: http://www.aberlericottages.co.uk

The (now quite messy) conditional CSS I have for smaller screens is:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
html, .header-bg {max-width: 100%;}
body {max-width: 100%; background: #eee;}
header {max-width: 100%;}
.wrapper, .grid_12, .wrapper-pad {max-width: 100%; height: auto;}
header nav ul.sf-menu {display: none;}                                        
#faded, #logo, #tail-top-left {display: none; height: 0px;}                       
.main, .container_12 {max-width: 100%; height: auto; margin:0;}                       
.container_12 .grid_8, .container_12 .grid_12, container_12, footer {max-width: 100%;}    
section#content {background: #eee; max-width: 100%; margin: 0;}                   
span, .grid_12, h2 {max-width: 100%;}                                         
p {max-width: 100%; padding-right: 5px;}                              
span.quality, div.quality {width: 200px; display:none;}                           
container_12.grid_12 {max-width: 100%;}                                       
footer strong.fright {float: none;}                                           
footer .grid_12 {padding: 8px 0 0;}                                           
footer.container_12 {max-width: 325px; margin:0;}                                 
footer {background: #211c1b; height: auto; padding-bottom: 6px; margin:0; max-width: 99%;}
nav ul     { display: none; }                                                 
nav select { display: inline-block;}                                              
.line-hor {display: none;}                                                    
img.fright {float: none;}                                                     
aside.row {max-width: 100%; margin: 0; padding:0; background: transparent;}
```

}

Which isn't great on the phone and doesn't pass Google PageSpeed Insight tests. Changing the CSS statement:

```
.wrapper, .grid_12, .wrapper-pad {max-width: 100%; height: auto;}
```

to

```
.wrapper, .grid_12, .wrapper-pad {max-width: 300px; height: auto;}
```

Fixes things as far as Google PageSpeed Insights is concerned, but then it looks terrible on the phone. Where am I going wrong? Why won't 100% work as the maximum width?

Answer (score 0):

Google won't allow content to exceed the viewport width, event if the container has overflow set to hidden. One way I found is to set the display of the overflowing content to none while outside the viewport and set to something else when needed back. 
A common case for these kind of pagespeed "errors" is off-canvas navigations.